# github: referring another project file revision

Tags: github

To prevent copy/pasting foreign code to my github repository I would like to refer from my project (in specific dir) another project files (of the specific revision)

To make things clear I'd like to achieve situation like in this repo: https://github.com/husio/vim-configuration/tree/master/bundle

How can I do so?

Not sure if it's a github only feature, or somehow git itself supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). It is a feature of git, but GitHub's file browser will resolve submodules when you view them on the site (which is what you can see in the repository you linked to).

Note that while submodules let you choose their location (within your repository), name, and commit (from the submodule's repository), they will include the entire trees of the original repositories. If you only want specific files or directories, check out [subtree merge](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-7.html) instead.